# How can I store an output of different loops and data into one variable?

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
    foreach($diff as $ident => $value){


                            foreach($properties as $key => $row){

                            if ($key == $ident){

                            echo "Name: ".$row["name"].". ";
                            echo "animal: ".$row["animal"].". ";
                            }
                            }

                            foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue ){

                            echo $innerKey."1: ";                               
                            echo $diff[$ident][$innerKey].PHP_EOL.". "; 

                            echo $innerKey."2: ";   
                            echo $diff2[$ident][$innerKey].PHP_EOL.". "; 


                            }

                        }
```

The output on my page is this:

*Name: Fred. animal: cat. food1: chicken . food2: milk . Name: sam. animal: dog. food1: ham . food2: apple . Name: alan. animal: bird. food1: cerials . food2: gras .*

I would like to store the whole text into one variable. is this possible?

Comment: @Jarla do you need one variable that is string or you need one variable that is array?

Comment: the variable needs to be a string

Comment: @Jarla Then check the answer down this example makes it string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it a string var then add this:

```
$string='';
foreach($diff as $ident => $value){
    foreach($properties as $key => $row){
        if ($key == $ident){
            $string .= "Name: ".$row["name"].". ";
            $string .= "animal: ".$row["animal"].". ";
        }
    }
    foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue ){
        $string .= $innerKey."1: ";                               
        $string .= $diff[$ident][$innerKey].PHP_EOL.". "; 
        $string .= $innerKey."2: ";   
        $string .= $diff2[$ident][$innerKey].PHP_EOL.". "; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh great, that is working very well. Thank you for your help :)